# VB.NET Option Compare Text does not work correctly in .NET 3.5

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-4.0, .net-3.5

I am working on a legacy Windows Form with VB.NET and I have recently discovered a confusing behavior.

There is project A that targets .NET 2.0 with Option Compare Text set at code file. Project A contains function CharacterFilter that uses method String.InStr. CharacterFilter will remove special characters from given string.

Project B references to project A. Project B targets .NET 3.5 and also set Option Compare Text at its code file.

Given input string as "123" and special characters to be removed are "²³", function CharacterFilter surprisingly does not remove "23" from given input string. However, if Project B is targetted .NET 4.0, "23" will be removed from given input string.

From Microsoft docs, setting Option Compare Text should remove "23" no matter what .net framework versions.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-compare-statement

Could someone help to point a Microsoft document reporting this behavior. Many thanks.

```
--Project A targets .NET 2.0
Option Compare Text
Public Class Backtool
    Function CharFilter(ByVal Text As String, ByVal Filter_Renamed As String) As String
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim vF As String
        Dim vPos As Integer

            For i = Len(Filter_Renamed) To 1 Step -1
                vF = Mid(Filter_Renamed, i, 1)
                vPos = InStr(Text, vF)
                Do While vPos > 0
                    Text = Mid(Text, 1, vPos - 1) & Mid(Text, vPos + 1)
                    vPos = InStr(Text, vF)
                Loop
            Next i
        
        CharFilter = Text
    End Function
End Class
```

```
--Project B that references project A
Option Compare Text
Module Module1
    Public BT As Backtool
    Sub Main()
        BT = New Backtool()
        Dim text = "123"
        Dim filterStr = "²³"
        Console.WriteLine("Result string is: " + BT.CharFilter(text, filterStr, False))
        --Returns "123" if targets .NET Framework 3.5
        --Returns "1" if targets .NET Framework 4.0
    End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 2):

I have reproduce your projects in Visual Studio 2010 and I have the same stranger error. I have read Microsoft documentation but I can't find the reason.

But, I'v found a work around... try to use `System.Text.NormalizationForm` inside the ProjectB

```
Option Compare Text
Imports System.Text

Public Class Backtool
    Function CharFilter(ByVal Text As String, ByVal Filter_Renamed As String) As String
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim vF As String
        Dim vPos As Integer

        'Try this
        Filter_Renamed = Filter_Renamed.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormKC)
        '

        For i = Len(Filter_Renamed) To 1 Step -1
            vF = Mid(Filter_Renamed, i, 1)
            vPos = InStr(Text, vF)
            Do While vPos > 0
                Text = Mid(Text, 1, vPos - 1) & Mid(Text, vPos + 1)
                vPos = InStr(Text, vF)
            Loop
        Next i
        CharFilter = Text
    End Function
End Class
```

Below Microsoft normalizationForm documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.normalizationform?view=netframework-2.0

I hope it is useful.